# CGS of resistance

Tags: electrical-resistance, units, si-units, metrology

What's the CGS unit of resistance?
Is it the same as that in SI system, i.e. ohm (Ω)?
I googled but found no explicit answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abohm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohm's law in terms of $emu-cgs$ units

> When a current of one abampere (1 abA) flows through a resistance of 1 abohm, the resulting potential difference across the component is one abvolt (1 abV).

1 $\Omega$ = $10^{9}$ $ab\Omega$

You can find more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abohm

Answer (score 1):

It is ab$\Omega$.
$$1 ab\Omega = 10^{-9} \Omega $$

In CGS system, unit of current is Biot (or Bi) which is equal to $10 \ \text{ampere}$.

Dimension of resistance is $ML^{2}T^{-3}A^{-2}$

In SI system mass is $10^{3}$ times; length is $10^{2}$ times; time is same while current is $1/10$ times. That makes $\Omega$ as $10^9$ times $ab\Omega$.